# How to use RotatingFileHandler with the root logger

Tags: python, logging

I configure the root logger:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Then I put log messages in my code like this:

```
logging.debug("This is a log message")
```

**Question**: How do I add a RotatingFileHandler such that my logs will be rotated?

Note: I **do not** want a logger instance which I then have to pass around everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `handlers` kwarg of basicConfig. Be aware that this needs to be an iterable and you can not use the filename argument together with it.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

rot_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('filename.txt')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, handlers=[rot_handler])
```

Link to relevant part of documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig

Comment: Thanks!
I was using filename and stream together (which does not work).